# How to handle NaN values when writing to a database which expects something else than type:float?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm working scraping project and I'm working with Postgres. I've set up all tables by hand which include the typical data types like datetime, integer, text and floats.

But I run into an issue. Since I scrape many fields, there are always some fields missing and they become nan. And since nan is type float I receive an error when I'm trying to push a float value into a Column which expects a, for instance, datetime or text object.

At least I believe so. The error message isn't very clear.

I'm basically using Pandas only (`df.to_sql`) after I've created the tables by SQLAlchemy's `declarative_base`.

My process is like:

```
obj = Scrape() # Scrape() includes all relevant methods
obj.get_data()
obj.create_a_df()
obj.df.to_sql('table', con=engine, [...])
```

As soon as a value within the current scrape (`obj.get_data()`) doesn't exist, it becomes `nan`. And since `nan` has type float, I can't post it into the table which expect anything else but float.

```
Error:
[SQL: INSERT INTO company_statistics (my column name) VALUES (my df_columns)]  [parameters: 
{my data as dictionary}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/9h9h)
```

Can't diagnose it very well, but I expect it to be the described reason above. Is there any way around? Does it make sense to `df.fillna(None)` or is there any keyword available I'm not aware of?

Comment: It's better let python infer the data types (let python create the table where data will be stored) and then normalize. Or use string data types in columns where an error is expected, then normalize.

Comment: Yes, but if I let python infer data types for the first time, that wouldn't guarantee that the second data set would work with it. What do you mean by normalize?

Comment: Bring into conformity with a standard (e.g. a data type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also consider [`obj.df.dropna(inplace=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna). This will simply drop all rows that contain `NaN` in any of the columns.

Comment: Yeah, typical Pandas. It's like opening an old drawer with tools, and finding the right one for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't getting rid of the `NaN`s fix this? Using `.fillna()` would replace all of the `NaN` values with whatever you declare inside. You could put this within your scraping method.